# Carrier HVAC System with Variable Speed Motor burned out after 6 months

Tags: hvac, air-conditioning, heat-pump, central-air, carrier

I just recently purchased a Carrier Hvac 3 ton heat pump system back in February of this year. The heat pump has a variable speed fan that just burned out. Is this common? This is a new system and it gets a lot of use (as I am in FL). It appears that these fan motors are manufactured by GE. How often am I going to have to replace this thing? Something this essential should not be breaking 6 months into use. I change filters often and use a MERV 11 filter. Am I doing something wrong that is causing this?

Comment: 6 months would mean a defect or installed wrong.  Would be talking to the installers to fix it, at their expense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As noted by crip659 in his [comment](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/254572/carrier-hvac-system-with-variable-speed-motor-burned-out-after-6-months#comment509737_254572), this is a warranty issue, not a DIY fix.

You should expect HVAC equipment to last 10-15 *years* at a *minimum* (we stretched our last system to 26 years). Life expectancy should *not* be measured in months.

This is either an improper installation or a poor quality fan motor that slipped through QC. It can happen and shouldn't be taken as a strike against the manufacturer.